# How do I merge two dictionaries in Smalltalk with a oneliner?

Tags: collections, smalltalk

There might exist dialect specific ways, or maybe a general one. I have two dictionaries, let's say:

```
a := {'a' -> 1} asDictionary.
b := {'b' -> 2} asDictionary.
```

Now I want to get `c` as the union of `a` and `b`.

Comment: Apart from the answers already given: "with a oneliner" - Just create a method for it if it doesn't statisfy the criteria. Readability comes first, way before cramming everything into one line.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on whether you want a third object or you prefer to include, say `b`, into `a`.

For the first case

```
c := Dictionary new.
a keysAndValuesDo: [:k :v | c at: k put: v].
b keysAndValuesDo: [:k :v | c at: k put: v].
```

For the second

```
b keysAndValuesDo: [:k :v | a at: k put: v].
```

Note also that the operation is not commutative, meaning that if the same key occurs in both dictionaries, the one that will survive in the result is the last added.

Answer (score 3):

Another one:

```
Dictionary new addAll: a; addAll: b; yourself
```

Also works when a and b are other collections of Associations, as in your question without asDictionary. Works at least in Squeak.

As pointed out by @aka.nice in the comments, depending on your Smalltalk implementation it may have the side effect of sharing the Association objects with the input dictionaries. It certainly is that way in Squeak. If a and b have common keys, it may even modify one of the input dictionaries (in Squeak a) because first an existing Association is added to the new Dictionary's hashtable, and then this Association gets the value from the other input Dictionary assigned.

```
a := Dictionary newFrom: {#a -> 1}.
b := Dictionary newFrom: {#a -> 2}.
c := Dictionary new addAll: a; addAll: b; yourself.
{a at: #a. b at: #a. c at: #a}  "==> #(2 2 2) in Squeak"
```

Comment: if a and b are already Dictionary, you can then `addAll: a associations` etc...

Comment: ... with the nasty side effect however that associations will then be shared. Modifying `a at: 'a' put: 4` will also modify c...

Comment: @aka.nice The code also works without sending #associations if a and b are dictionaries.

Comment: oh great, I see how it works now. The funny thing is that associations are still shared. Moreover, in case of overlapping keys, the first dictionary (a) will share the association, and thus will be modified. Example: `a := {'c'->0} as:Dictionary.
b := {'c'->7} as:Dictionary.
Dictionary new addAll: a; addAll: b; yourself.
^a at: 'c'.` will answer 7

Comment: @aka.nice Indeed, I edited that into the answer yesterday after replying to your comment :-)

Answer (score 3):

In Squeak/Pharo you can simply use `union:`

```
a := {'a' -> 1} as: Dictionary.
b := {'b' -> 2} as: Dictionary.
c := a union: b.

-> a Dictionary('a'->1 'b'->2 )
```

Note that the elements of b will be chosen in case of overlapping keys

```
a := {'a' -> 1. 'c'->0} as:Dictionary.
b := {'b' -> 2. 'c'->7} as:Dictionary.
c := a union: b.

-> a Dictionary('a'->1 'b'->2 'c'->7 )
```

Answer (score 2):

`c := a, b` works in Pharo (but not in Dolphin)

Comment: I don't like it... the binary message `,` so far has only ever been used for sequences (SequenceableCollection) for which it is very natural. Dictionary are unordered and overlapping keys will be fused. Considering that Pharo has `union:` too, that's a poor choice IMO.

Comment: Note that this poor choice was made in Squeak originally, not in Pharo.

Answer (score 2):

I think [Leandro's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65598642/6059896) and [aka.nice's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65604650/6059896) answer provide you with nice solutions.  Both also mention that you are going to lose information when the key is same for both of the dictionaries.

I'm writing this in order to complement these answers.  If you should need to keep the duplicate `key -> value` I would do it the following way:

```
a := {'a' -> 1. 'c'->3} as: Bag.
b := {'b' -> 2. 'c'->20} as: Bag.
c := a union: b.
```

Which will give you a Bag with Dictionary as contents:

`Dictionary('b'->2->1 'a'->1->1 'c'->20->1 'c'->3->1)`

(I'm using Smalltalk/X-jv)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner that should work in any Smalltalk, but might share associations:

```
 c := (a associations, b associations) asDictionary
```

Next is a version that should work in any Smalltalk without risk of sharing associations,
and is what both (c := a, b) and (c := a union: b) *should* be doing
in all of them:

```
  c := (a associations, b associations)
            inject: Dictionary new
              into: [:all :each|
                     all at: each key put: each value
                         ; yourself
                    ]
```

Finally, this last one should also work in any version of Smalltalk,
without risk of either sharing associations or losing any information:

```
  c := (a associations, b associations)
            inject: Dictionary new
              into: [:all :each|
                     (all at: each key ifAbsentPut: List new)
                          add: each value
                          ; yourself
                    ]
```